# Is there a method to truncate/set the EOF of a file in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, file, operating-system

I have found the function SetEndOfFile() in C++ which can truncate the file, is there a similar method in VB.NET?
I need this feature because this can help me edit a huge file quickly. If I overwrite the whole file from the very start just for eliminate last bytes that will take a lot of time.
If such method doesn't exsit in VB.NET, do you have a plan B for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, see the [FileStream.SetLength(Int64) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.setlength?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @AndrewMorton You are a life saver. Thank you for your help! Now my graduation project went easy!